# How to grant access to virtual environment to other users on CentOS server

Tags: python, ssh, centos, virtualenv

I used this tutorial (rec by GoDaddy because I have a GoDaddy VPS)

https://www.godaddy.com/garage/how-to-install-and-configure-python-on-a-hosted-server/

to install a secondary version of Python (3.6.6) and create a Virtual Environment to run modules with the secondary version of Python.  I want to be able to run scripts in the virtual environment but do not want to always use the admin account to do this.  I have one other account set up that does not have admin privileges.  Is there a way to extend authority to more than the admin account that created it?  Do I need to do a virtual environment on every user account that is going to have access to run python?

It says to add a line to the bash_profile script.  The script already had this:

```
# .bash_profile

# Get the aliases and functions
if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then
     . ~/.bashrc
fi

# User specific environment and startup programs

PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin

export PATH
```

This makes sense in that it seems to be defining the location of underlying Python (i.e., 2.6.6).  I have modules in a `venv` that require 3.4+ so I created the virtual environment.  I want to be able to call the script from Chrome and run it for some scripts and run it from cronjob for other scripts and the scripts need to always point to the virtualenv to use that installed interpreter.  I have no idea how to do this correctly.   Here's my system information and the results of some SSH printouts:

```
$ cd $PATH
-bash: cd: /home/flohosti/.local/bin:/home/flohosti/perl5/bin:/usr/local/cpanel/3rdparty/lib/path-bin:/usr/local/cpanel/3rdparty/lib/path-bin:/usr/local/cpanel/3rdparty/lib/path-bin:/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/cpanel/composer/bin: No such file or directory
```

Before going into the VirtualEnv I run `which python` and get /usr/bin/python which I expected.

Comment: Sorry but i did not really get what your question is? Can you explain in some more clarity ?

Comment: When you install a virtualenv, it is accessible by the admin that installs it (and root).  It is not accessible to the other user accounts on the server.  I want to allow other users to run code in that virutalenv with Python 3.6.6 instead of the default Python 2.6.6.,

Comment: Please do not make more work for people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on Stack Overflow, you've granted a non-revocable right for SO to distribute that content under the [CC BY-SA 3.0 license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/). By SO policy, any vandalism will be reverted.

Comment: Then get people to explain to me why my post has been downvoted.  If it's so bad, why shouldn't it be deleted?  Isn't the point of SO for people to get help?  I was asking for help and get down voted without any explanation as to why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple ways to do that.

You can simply give read access to the directory where virtual environment is installed and then export its path in `/etc/profile` so that its automatically added to every users path.

Or you can give access to python binary inside the virtual env folder.

That being said this isn't the right way to go about it, most of the times you would want to have virtual environment inside your projet folder so that it is automatically available the project and who so ever has access to that project.

**Edit 1**

So the answer to your comment

Yes absolutely you can use the same virtual env to execute script in `cron` but you have to give absolute path to virtaul environment and your script in cron, like `/home/flohosti/projectOne/env/bin/python <script path>` or you can just set the  `PATH` in cron and then you can use relative path as well.

Comment: "and who so ever has access to that project".....that's exactly what I'm asking.  How do I give people access to that project?

Comment: Project is nothing more than a directory on the file system, so giving access to project is nothing more than giving access to that directory. And that you can easily do via managing user, group permissions or ownership or using ACLs.

Comment: OK.  So assuming that I'm able to give user: flohosti permission to access the folder where the virtualenv is located, what shebang would I put at the top of the script so I could run the script via chome?

Comment: Yes absolutely but you have to give absolute path in cron, like `/home/flohosti/projectOne/env/bin/python <script path>`.

Comment: Please consider upvoting the answer if it helped you.

Comment: it involved granting access permission of that user to the folder where the `virtualenv` was located and then I took the results of which python and used that in the shebang so the script used the correct interpreter.

Comment: That's how you would have to do it.